# Windows : How to list files recursively with size and last access date?

Tags: windows, powershell, console

I need a simple way to create a list of all files in a certain folder. (recursively)

Each file must be in a single line. I also need the file size and the last access date in the same line, separated by a special character.

The output (textfile) should look like this:

```
c:\folder\file1.txt|400|2012-11-12 15:23:08
c:\folder\file2.txt|200|2012-11-12 15:23:08
c:\folder\file3.txt|100|2012-11-12 15:23:08
c:\folder\sub folder\file4.txt|500|2012-11-12 15:23:08
```

'Dir' seems not to be an option, because the German Special characters get messed up that way. (öäüß)

Powershell handles the special characters well, but I couldn't make it so that the information for one file ends up in a single line:

```
get-childitem D:\temp -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |  foreach-object -process {$_.FullName, $_.LastWriteTime, $_.Length}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try this:

```
get-childitem D:\temp -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} |
select-object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path file.csv
```

Comment: not bad, but it kills the german "Umlaute" : "D:\temp\????????????????\boink.txt"|"05.11.2012 15:31:28"|"0"

Comment: i added -encoding default to the export-csv cmdlet and it works!

Comment: @BaineWedlock Good! Forgot to mention `-encoding` parameter!

Comment: A trivial point, but note that LastAccessTime isn't the same thing as LastWriteTime (since "last access date" was mentioned in the title).

Comment: @G.Lombard Yes, but IIRC I copied what the user used in OP example. ;)