# How to get the size of all files in a directory, including all subdirectory,on windows 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, ls, fileinfo

I want get the size of all files in a directory, include subdirectory ,like ls command on linux .

Who can help me ?

Comment: maybe a duplicated of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345066/windows-how-to-list-files-recursively-with-size-and-last-access-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use to make use of software called TreeSize https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/